# How to remap keys in ido-find-file?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, ido-mode

I have been trying to make a few changes to ido-mode to make it more useful. One of the things which I have been trying to do is to remap some of the keys which I use in `ido-find-file`. The main one is that I want to use <kbd>C-d</kbd> to call the `ido-enter-dired` function instead of having to press <kbd>C-f</kbd>+<kbd>C-d</kbd> which does the same thing.

This is my ido setup so far:

```
(defun ali/ido ()
  "My configuration for ido-mode"
  (require 'ido)
  (setq ido-create-new-buffer 'always)

  ;; Making sure that ido works in M-x
  (global-set-key
      "\M-x"
      (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (call-interactively
          (intern
          (ido-completing-read
          "M-x "
          (all-completions "" obarray 'commandp))))))

  ;; Ido keybindings
  (defun ido-keybindings ()
    (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-d") 'ido-enter-dired))


  (add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-keybindings)

  (ido-everywhere t)
  (ido-mode 1))
```

However whenever, I try to use <kbd>C-d</kbd> in `ido-find-file` I always get this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When called with the minibuffer active, your command uses a recursive minibuffer to read input using `ido-completing-read`.

Use this as your command instead:

```lisp
(lambda ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((enable-recursive-minibuffers  t)) ; <=====================
    (call-interactively
     (intern
      (ido-completing-read
       "M-x "
       (all-completions "" obarray 'commandp))))))
```

`C-h v enable-recursive-minibuffers` tells us:

> `enable-recursive-minibuffers` is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means to **allow minibuffer commands while in the minibuffer**.
>
> This variable makes a difference whenever the minibuffer window is active.
> Also see `minibuffer-depth-indicate-mode`, which may be handy if this
> variable is non-`nil`.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Thanks, this works with M-x and I will see if it will let me use it with the keybindings for `ido-find-file`